# Exception creating table with Dandelion DataTables

Tags: java, jsp, datatables, dandelion

I am trying to create table using `Dandelion` library and I am following their documentation [Dandelion](http://dandelion.github.io/components/datatables/1.1.0/docs/html/) but for some reason it is throwing huge exception. I've configured the entries in my web.xml and I have the tag in my jsp page as well. The table doesn't have anything except the title because I am still exploring it. :)

pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.dandelion</groupId>
        <artifactId>datatables-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

web.xml

```
<!-- Dandelion servlet definition and mapping -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dandelionServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.github.dandelion.core.web.DandelionServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dandelionServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/dandelion-assets/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Dandelion filter definition and mapping -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>dandelionFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.github.dandelion.core.web.DandelionFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>dandelionFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="datatables" uri="http://github.com/dandelion/datatables" %>

<datatables:table id="myTableId" data="${intgList}" sortable="true">
    <datatables:column title="Line of Business">

    </datatables:column>
</datatables:table>
```

stacktrace:

```
org.apache.tiles.request.render.CannotRenderException: ServletException including path '/jsps/template/template.jsp'.
at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:399)
at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:238)
at org.apache.tiles.TilesContainerWrapper.render(TilesContainerWrapper.java:103)
at org.apache.tiles.impl.mgmt.CachingTilesContainer.render(CachingTilesContainer.java:126)
at org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult.doExecute(TilesResult.java:161)
at org.apache.struts2.result.StrutsResultSupport.execute(StrutsResultSupport.java:208)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:373)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:277)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:253)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:177)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:260)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:73)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.doIntercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:139)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:133)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:133)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:192)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:69)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.DateTextFieldInterceptor.intercept(DateTextFieldInterceptor.java:115)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:88)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:99)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:139)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:155)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:174)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:120)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:171)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:195)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:193)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
at com.mercuryinsurance.esignature.common.interceptor.ESignatureUIActivityInterceptor.intercept(ESignatureUIActivityInterceptor.java:35)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
at com.mercuryinsurance.esignature.integration.interceptor.ESignatureIntegrationInterceptor.intercept(ESignatureIntegrationInterceptor.java:145)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:247)
at org.apache.struts2.factory.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:564)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:81)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:143)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:213)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at com.github.dandelion.core.web.DandelionFilter.doFilter(DandelionFilter.java:128)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: ServletException including path '/jsps/template/template.jsp'.
at org.apache.tiles.request.servlet.ServletUtil.wrapServletException(ServletUtil.java:61)
at org.apache.tiles.request.servlet.ServletRequest.forward(ServletRequest.java:267)
at org.apache.tiles.request.servlet.ServletRequest.doForward(ServletRequest.java:228)
at org.apache.tiles.request.AbstractClientRequest.dispatch(AbstractClientRequest.java:57)
at org.apache.tiles.request.render.DispatchRenderer.render(DispatchRenderer.java:47)
at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:259)
at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:397)
... 96 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: JSPException including path '/jsps/integration/integrationView.jsp'.
at org.apache.tiles.request.servlet.ServletUtil.wrapServletException(ServletUtil.java:61)
at org.apache.tiles.request.jsp.JspRequest.doInclude(JspRequest.java:125)
at org.apache.tiles.request.AbstractViewRequest.dispatch(AbstractViewRequest.java:47)
at org.apache.tiles.request.render.DispatchRenderer.render(DispatchRenderer.java:47)
at org.apache.tiles.request.render.ChainedDelegateRenderer.render(ChainedDelegateRenderer.java:68)
at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:259)
at org.apache.tiles.TilesContainerWrapper.render(TilesContainerWrapper.java:108)
at org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.renderAttribute(InsertAttributeModel.java:188)
at org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.execute(InsertAttributeModel.java:132)
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.doTag(InsertAttributeTag.java:299)
at org.apache.jsp.jsps.template.template_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f2(template_jsp.java:152)
at org.apache.jsp.jsps.template.template_jsp._jspService(template_jsp.java:87)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
at org.apache.tiles.request.servlet.ServletRequest.forward(ServletRequest.java:265)
... 101 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to java.util.List
at com.github.dandelion.datatables.jsp.tag.TableTag.doEndTag(TableTag.java:248)
at org.apache.jsp.jsps.integration.integrationView_jsp._jspx_meth_datatables_005ftable_005f0(integrationView_jsp.java:716)
at org.apache.jsp.jsps.integration.integrationView_jsp._jspService(integrationView_jsp.java:221)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:605)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:544)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:954)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:684)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:678)
at org.apache.tiles.request.jsp.JspRequest.doInclude(JspRequest.java:123)
... 127 more
ERROR DefaultDispatcherErrorHandler Exception occurred during processing request: org.apache.tiles.request.render.CannotRenderException: ServletException including path '/jsps/template/template.jsp'.
```

Comment: It looks like, no one is using Dandelion :)

Answer (score 0):

According to exception,  `intgList` returns BigDecimal, instead of List, you must change it to return to list.